# React Native and Flow Compatibility History

Tags: react-native, flowtype

When a new version of react native is launched, after doing `react-native init` it comes with a `.flowconfig` file update.

is it there any history or `.flowconfig` files so that I can match a given react native version?

Comment: Have you tried digging into the react-native cli for figure out where it's coming from? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/react-native-cli

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/local-cli (I don't use react native)